# golang pprof for c library code

Tags: go, cgo, pprof

I have been trying to profile my golang application with pprof, but it seems that the details of my c code(linked as static library) is missed in the output result.

[flame graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uwqH.png)

From the frame graph you can see all the c code time consuming is reported within "runtime._ExternalCode", no details at all. And I am very sure my static library is compiled with debug enable.

So Is there any way to make the pprof get the details(like stack trace) of 3rd party c code? Or Is there any other golang profiling tool to do this?

Comment: No, `runtime/pprof` can't record profile data from C code.